# User Roles gone after restarting ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, roles

I am working on a project that has different User Roles. I have an Admin Link that is displayed if the User is an admin and hidden if not. I am using:

```
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
          @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "AdminIndex", "Account")</li>
            }
```

It is working fine when I login initially, however when I am running the project locally and stop it, then restart it, my User Name (with the Admin role) is still logged in, however the Admin link disappears and I have to logout and then log back in the same user to get the Admin link to show. Is there any way to get it to remember the role of the user when restarting the project.

I think the way its remembering the username and password when the project is restarted is this in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid && 
  WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, 
  persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
  {
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
  }


  ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is 
  incorrect.");
  return View(model);
}
```

But I am not sure because it came built in to the project. Do I need to add an Action for my user roles link with something to do with Cookie in my Role Model like in the Login Model?

Comment: perhaps, use a `session timeout`? Store the `intial_login_time/last_active_time` of the user, and before serving any page check if that time difference is within the timeout limits, this way when you restart the application, the `intial_login_time` will be null...

Comment: I was actually able to do this using   [InitializeSimpleMembership] on the HomeController only had it on the account Controller